# Matrix multiplication with multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

What is the quickest way to multiply a matrix against a numpy array of vectors? I need to multiply a matrix A by every single vector in a list of 1000 vectors. Using a for loop is taking too long, so I was wondering if there's a way to multiply them all at once?

Example:

```
arr = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1],[1,1,1]]

A=
[2 2 2]
[2 2 2]
```

So I need to multiply Av for each v in arr. The result:

```
arr = [[6,6], [6,6], [6,6]]
```

Is there a faster way than:

```
new_arr = []
for v in arr:
    sol = np.matmul(A, v)
    new_arr.append(sol)
```

Comment: What kind of multiplication? Elementwise across rows?

Comment: Please provide sample data with expected output.

Comment: Your terminology is a little vague.  What's the shape of `A`.  Is the other thing a list or array?  If array what's the dtype?  What's the shape of the 'vectors'?

Comment: The basic rule for `matmul` (and `dot`) is last dimension of `A` pairs with the 2nd to the last of `B` (or the only one of `v`).  Have you tried `matmul(A, arr.T)`?

Comment: If `A` is (2,3) and `arr` is (4,3)`, it should be clearer that you want to pair the 3's, and get a (2,4) or (4,2) result.  To get that a transpose of either `A` or `arr` is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want a dot product:

```
new_arr = np.dot(arr, A.T)
```

where `arr` and `A` are numpy arrays:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
A = np.array([[2,2, 2],[2,2,2]])
```

Result:

```
array([[6, 6],
       [6, 6],
       [6, 6]])
```

According to your edit, the dot product you want may be:

```
new_arr = np.dot(A, arr).T
```

Both return the same, but it's not the same computation.

Comment: What is A.T in this case?

Comment: The transpose of `A` using numpy.

Comment: Depending on the content of the two matrices, what you want may also be `np.dot(A, arr).T`. Might be this you want according to your edit.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. Basically I have a matrix of dimension 50 x 30000. And I need to multiply this matrix by every vector in a numpy array. There are 500 vectors of dim=30000. Would this still be correct?

Comment: More simply, `arr.dot(A.T)`

Comment: ValueError: shapes (50,30000) and (500,30000) not aligned: 61200 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)

Comment: If you dot product your two matrixes you'll get a 50x500 matrix. That what you expecting?

Comment: @AP730 yes, then np.dot is what you are looking for. The second form is probably what you want, multiplying A by each vector and then transposing the result.

Comment: I'm looking to get an array of 500 vectors each with dim = 50.

Comment: @AP730 make sure you transpose what you need to transpose and that `arr` is what you said it was. If it's different, then you need to adapt the formula to transpose what you need. Seems like know it's np.dot(A, arr.T) if A if (50x30000) and arr (500,30000).

Comment: I think there is some confusion about what is what dimension. Pay attention to the dimensions. But with dot, you will get the answer you need, as long as you use dimensions properly. dot(A, arr) is if arr has n vector of size 30000, but if you created your matrix with 30000 vectors of size n, then you need to transpose. numpy uses C order, different than Matlab.

Comment: Oh shoot. Thank you so much! I completely got my two matrices backwards. It works now :)